# pkg_resources: The 'sh' distribution was not found and is requred by buildozer

Tags: python, linux, debian, buildozer

Using debian, seems like installed all dependencies

sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev libssl-dev
pip3 install --user --upgrade Cython==0.29.19 virtualenv  # the --user should be removed if you do this in a venv

added the following line at the end of your ~/.bashrc file
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/

did clone git, installed

Answer (score 0):

Installed from pip not from git and it worked.